# Как скрыть приложение из списка недавно запущенных приложений?

Tags: java, android

При написани приложения столкнулся с такой проблемой: нужно запустить его как `homescreen` и убрать из списка `recent apps`.
Пробовал добовлять в манифест `android:excludeFromRecents="true"` и `android:noHistory="true"`, но всё безрезультатно, приложение по прежнему висит в списке. Пробовал так же убирать иконку приложения через:

`PackageManager pm = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(getComponentName(), PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);`

Но, как и ожидалось, помимо скрытия приложения из recent apps, оно пропало и в меню выбора лаунчера.

Comment: Ээээ... А зачем вам? Благопристойное приложение не должно скрываться от пользователя.

Comment: @VladD, а неблагопристойное?

Comment: @0xFFh: Ну, если человек пишет вредоносный код, то пускай сам доходит до решения проблем. Анекдот про талибанский вирус помните? Вот.

Comment: Ну, я пишу приложение для себя, на замену стандартному homescreen'у, у меня очень специфические вкусы и хочется отойти от опщепринятых канонов. Комментарии не по делу, мы здесь собрались, чтобы подозревать друг друга?

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку, alexander barakin, буду придерживаться данных правил.

Comment: @Максим: Ну, вы могли бы объяснить в двух словах, в чём дело. Не хочется помогать писать вредоносный программы, знаете ли.

Comment: @VladD, вот я так сейчас прочитал свой вопрос... Есть такое, но я расчитывал на то, что люди знают, что каждый уважающий себя лаунчер так делает, по ряду технических причин и подумают прежде всего на него, но прогадался немного. Кстати, вы не знаете кто написал этот сайт? Я хочу поклоняться этому человеку. Этот код достоин лишь восхищения, вот бы все так писали...

Comment: @Максим: Насколько я понимаю, начинал проект [Jeff Atwood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeff_Atwood), а сейчас его продолжает большая команда.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно добавить в активность рабочего стола вот такую последовательность `internet-filter`:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.MONKEY"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

У меня была проблема при первом запуске, тогда приложение отображалось в `recent apps`, но когда я выбрал его как дефолтное, то из списка оно пропало.